# Why is a FlagSet not correctly parsing these args?

Tags: go

Here's a simplified code snippet:  the context for this in a real project is that I have a command-line app that's parsing arguments input to the program, and then individual commands that parse the remaining args after the command name is pulled out.  I'm using a FlagSet per command, but for some reason, it won't ever actually parse out flags:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"flag"
)

func main() {
    args := []string{"arg", "-flag", "value"}
    flags := flag.NewFlagSet("flags", flag.ExitOnError)
    flagValue := flags.String("flag", "defaultValue", "")

    flags.Parse(args)
    fmt.Println(flags.Args(), *flagValue)

}
```

I'd expect the output to be: [arg] value, but instead I get: [arg -flag value] defaultValue

Code:  http://play.golang.org/p/D4RKPpVODF

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments in your `args` array are in the wrong order.  The non-flag arguments have to come after the flag arguments.  So you should write:

```
args := []string{"-flag", "value", "arg"}
```

Then the output is what you expected:

```
[arg] value
```

Code: http://play.golang.org/p/cv972SLZfG

Comment: interesting, thanks...is it common for argument parsers to be order-sensitive?  I feel like i've seen a number of command-line tools that accept things like './mytool arg1 -flag1=1 -flag2=2' as well as './mytool -flag1=1 -flag2=2 arg1' etc.

Comment: @user3179836: POSIX requires that the first non-option stop option processing, but most people are familiar with the gnu style, where you can give options in arbitrary order, stopping processing with `--` if it's required. In other words, it's completely up to the command and the library it uses.